# Why is my empty object in useState hook rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just refreshing myself on functional components and react state hooks, building a simple react todo list app- all the simple functionalities are built out but I have this one bug during initial state where there is an empty task rendering in the list. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

App.js:

```
import TodoList from './TodoList'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>

      <TodoList /> 

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Todolist.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import NewTodoForm from './NewTodoForm'
import Todo from './Todo'

const TodoList = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
      list: [{title: "", id: ""}]
    })

    const addTodo = (newTodo) => {
        setState({ 
            list: [...state.list, newTodo]
         })
         console.log('after state change in addtodo', state.list.title)

    }

    const remove = (toDoId) => {
        console.log('logging remove')
        setState({
            list: state.list.filter(todo => todo.id !== toDoId)
        })
    }

    const strike = e => {
            const element = e.target;
            element.classList.toggle("strike");
    } 

    const update = (id, updatedTask) => {
        //i cant mutate state directly so i need to make a new array and set that new array in the state
        const updatedTodos = state.list.map(todo => {
            if (todo.id === id) { // find the relevant task first by mapping through existing in state and add updated info before storing it in updatedtodos
                return { ...todo, title: updatedTask}
            }
                return todo
        })
        console.log('updated todos', updatedTodos)
        setState({
            list: updatedTodos
        })
        console.log('list after updating state')
    }
    return (
        <div className="TodoList">
            <h1>Todo List<span>A simple react app</span></h1>
                <NewTodoForm addingTodo={addTodo}/> 

            { state.list.map(todo => <Todo id={todo.id} key={todo.id} title={todo.title} updateTodo={update} strikeThrough={strike} removeTodo={() => remove(todo.id)} />) }
           
          
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoList
```

Todo.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const Todo = ({id, title, removeTodo, strikeThrough, updateTodo}) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        isEditing: false,
    })

    const [task, setTask] = useState(title);



    const handleUpdate = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        updateTodo(id, task)
        setState({ isEditing: false})
    }

    const updateChange = (e) => {
    //    setState({...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
       setTask(e.target.value)
       console.log(task)

    }

    return (
        <div>
            {state.isEditing ? 
            <div className="Todo">
                <form className="Todo-edit-form" onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={task}
                        name="task"
                        onChange={updateChange}
                    >
                    </input>
                    <button>Submit edit</button>
                </form>
            </div> : 
            <div className="Todo">
                <ul>
                <li className="Todo-task" onClick={strikeThrough}>{title}</li>
            </ul>
            <div className="Todo-buttons">
            <button onClick={() => setState({isEditing: !state.isEditing})}><i class='fas fa-pen' /></button>
            <button onClick={removeTodo}><i class='fas fa-trash' /></button>
            </div>
            </div>
                }
           
        </div>
    )
}

export default Todo
```

Comment: Because you start with an empty task in the list `list: [{title: "", id: ""}]`, though this is expected so you can enter a new todo isn't it? Or am I misunderstanding your problem?

Comment: Hi @Dominic, thanks for your response. I need to initialise the state to empty strings first before setting the state, so i'm not sure thats the issue..

Comment: You mean you need to render empty task in the intial render and when a taske has added  you want to remove the empty task?

Comment: Hi @SaeedShamloo, not quite. i don't want the empty object rendering/showing up at all.. i've never experienced this issue before lol

Comment: Why don't you initialize list with empty array, like this: `list: []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rendering your to-do's with:

```
{ state.list.map(todo => <Todo id={todo.id} key={todo.id} title={todo.title} updateTodo={update} strikeThrough={strike} removeTodo={() => remove(todo.id)} />) }
```

Your initial state is:

```
{ list: [{title: "", id: ""}] }
```

The above state will cause React to render an empty to-do item for you. Once you clear the array, you should not see anything. Another option is to change your rendering and add a conditional that checks if to-do item values are empty, to not render them.

Comment: Hi @akds, thanks for the suggestion. I figured i might have to do this and added `todo.title === '' ? '' :` in the map for the rendering...so it doesnt render anymore but i'd still like to know why an empty object still renders in react state hook- thanks for your observations.

Comment: The array is empty => no rendering, array contains items => render occurs. If items in the array have missing fields, i.e. "do not fit", react will throw an error, but as long as the code fits (and it does have value, in your case empty string) it will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The initial state in TodoList seems to be having list:[{title: "", id: ""}], which contains empty title and id. Since it's mapped to create Todo, I think it starts with an empty Todo.